# Read and convert monthly grid excel file data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel-reader, parseexcel

I tried to read monthly food menu from excel in javascript (actually .net core mvc project). But the excel template not usual, the excel data looks like a monthly, how can I parse and read this ?
[image]